# Get the sum of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to sum the below column. How can I do it?

When I use

```
sum(DATEDIFF ( HOUR , startDate, endDate) / 10.0 )
```

it gives this output:

```
(No column name)
1.000000
0.300000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
0.300000
```

how can I sum this column?

the whole query:

```
SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF ( HOUR , StartTime , EndTime ) / 10.0 ) FROM [y]
     INNER JOIN [x] ON [x].UserID = [y].ID  
WHERE StartTime BETWEEN '20120709' AND '20120714' AND UserID = 1
    GROUP BY StartTime, [y].ID, [y].Name, EndTime 
    ORDER BY StartTime
```

Comment: do you have other columns in your select list? you could give full sql query..

Comment: Do you have a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: The sum will be over each of the GROUP BY columns.  This is the purpose of group by.  Remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a GROUP BY clause and shouldn't. Remove it and try again.

If that's not right and you do need it, then we need more information, please! What result are you trying to get?

If you GROUP BY a column, then for each different value in that column you will get a separate row.

Stop looking at the query and give an *example* result you'd like to see. Or tell us the question you want to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your GROUP BY clause.  It is causing the multiple rows. If you only want one sum, then ORDER BY is also unneeded.